# How can I fill in letters to blank space in Hangman Game if word contains letter?

Tags: java, jframe, jlabel, jtextfield

[image]I'm making a hangman game and I'm stumped on how I can fill the letter into the correct blank space if the word contains the letter. For example:

word: hello

blank spaces: _ _ _ _ _

user input: e

blank spaces: _ e _ _ _

Here is all my code, it is not an SSCCE but I've uploaded the image to along with this post.If you have any suggestions, please say. Thanks.

```
    package Game;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

class GameStructure {
    private String []wordList = {"javatar","java","activity","alaska","appearance","article",
            "automobile","basket","birthday","canada","central","character","chicken","chosen",
            "cutting","daily","darkness","diagram","disappear","driving","effort","establish","exact",
            "establishment","fifteen","football","foreign","frequently","frighten","function","gradually",
            "hurried","identity","importance","impossible","invented","italian","journey","lincoln",
            "london","massage","minerals","outer","paint","particles","personal","physical","progress",
            "quarter","recognise","replace","rhythm","situation","slightly","steady","stepped",
            "strike","successful","sudden","terrible","traffic","unusual","volume","yesterday"};
   private JTextField tf;
   private JLabel jl2;
   static String letter;
   static int []length = new int[64];

   public void window() {
       JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
       JMenu menu = new JMenu("File");
       menu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_A);
       menuBar.add(menu);
       JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem("Developer", KeyEvent.VK_T);
    menu.add(menuItem);
    JMenuItem menuItem2 = new JMenuItem("Instructions", KeyEvent.VK_T);
    menu.add(menuItem2);
    JMenuItem menuItem3 = new JMenuItem("Restart", KeyEvent.VK_T);
    menu.add(menuItem3);
    JMenuItem menuItem4 = new JMenuItem("Exit", KeyEvent.VK_T);
    menu.add(menuItem4);

       ImageIcon ic = new ImageIcon("hangman2.png");
      JFrame gameFrame = new JFrame();
      JPanel bottomRight = new JPanel();
      JPanel bottomLeft = new JPanel();
      JPanel top = new JPanel();
      JPanel bottom = new JPanel();
      JPanel imgPane = new JPanel();
      JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
      bottom.setLayout(new BoxLayout(bottom, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
      imgPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      panel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      panel1.setOpaque(false);//!!
      top.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(""));
      bottom.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(""));
      tf = new JTextField(1);
      JLabel img = new JLabel(ic, JLabel.CENTER);
      JLabel jl = new JLabel("Enter a letter", JLabel.CENTER);
      jl2 = new JLabel("Letters used:  ", JLabel.CENTER);
      JLabel jl3 = new JLabel("__ ", JLabel.CENTER);
      jl.setFont(new Font("Rockwell", Font.PLAIN, 20));
      tf.setFont(new Font("Rockwell", Font.PLAIN, 20));
      jl2.setFont(new Font("Rockwell", Font.PLAIN, 20));
      imgPane.add(img);//center
      top.add(jl);//top center
      top.add(tf);//top center
      bottomLeft.add(jl2);//bottom left position
      bottomRight.add(jl3);//bottom right position
      bottom.add(bottomLeft);//bottom
      bottom.add(bottomRight);//bottom
      panel1.add(imgPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);//background image (center)
      panel1.add(top, BorderLayout.NORTH);//text field and jlabel (top)
      panel1.add(bottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);// blank spaces and letters used (bottom)
      gameFrame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
      gameFrame.setTitle("Hangman");
      gameFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      gameFrame.setIconImage(
      new ImageIcon("hangmanIcon.png").getImage());
      gameFrame.setResizable(false);
      gameFrame.add(panel1);
      gameFrame.setSize(800, 500);
      gameFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      gameFrame.setVisible(true);

          int j = 0;
          for(j = 0; j<64; j++) {
             length[j] = wordList[j].length();//gets length of words in wordList
          }//end for
          int l = 0;
          String line = "";
          //create line first then put into .setText
          for(int m = 0; m<length[l]; m++) {
              line += "__ ";
              l++;
          }//end for
          jl3.setText(line);


          tf.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          @Override
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {//when enter key pressed
              JTextField tf = (JTextField)e.getSource();
             letter = tf.getText();
              jl2.setText(jl2.getText() + letter + " ");//sets jlabel text to users entered letter

              int k = 0;
              for(k = 0; k<64;){
                  if(wordList[k].contains(letter)){
                      System.out.println(letter);
                     break;
                  }else{
                      System.out.println("letter not in word");
                      break;
                  }
              }

              }//end actionPerformed method
          });
      }//end window method
   }

public class GameMain {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      GameStructure game = new GameStructure();
      game.window();
   }
}
```

Comment: What is the output you get now?

Comment: @mico currently I'm able to identify whether the word contains the letter inputed by the user or not, however this is all outputted to the console. Right now I'm trying to figure out how to fill in the letter the user inputed to the appropriate blank space on the JLabel

Comment: Sibbo was faster than me, you have already a promising suggestion about answer..

Comment: How this game works? If I press letter "k" you search every word in wordList for that letter?

Comment: In a normal game of hangman, he would only have one word. So I assume he is grabbing a random word from that list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can get the text of your `JLabel` with `getText()`, then edit the `String`, and then apply the result with `setText(String)`.

You just have to calculate the correct positions where you should insert the letters.

```
char[] jlabelText = yourJLabel.getText().toCharArray();

for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
    if (word.charAt(i) == userEnteredChar) {
        jlabelText[3 * i] = ' ';
        jlabelText[3 * i + 1] = userEnteredChar;
    }
}

yourJLabel.setText(String.valueOf(jlabelText));
```

Comment: I'm having difficulty calculating the correct position of the users inputed letter on the blank spaces. I've already figured out how to identify whether or not the letter entered is in the word.

Comment: Would it be a good idea to use .indexOf to calculate the letters position in the word then insert it based on that?

Comment: No, that doesn't work if the letter occurrs more than one time. My answer contains the code that replaces the correct characters to show the letter at the right positions.

Comment: I'm confused with your variables, can you please use my variables so I can better understand the code?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know what your variables mean. yourJLabel is the JLabel that is displaying the _ _ _ at the start. userEnteredChar is the character the user entered.

Comment: I got it to work, but can you explain why you're multiplying by 3?

Comment: Your JLabel has `"__ __ __ __ "` as text hasn't it? Every letter is 3 chars long.

Comment: Can you please clarify your logic? What do you mean every letter is 3 chars long?

Comment: Well, you create the string with "__ " for every character, or do you?

Comment: yes, can you continue explaining. I still don't understand the every letter is 3 chars long part. Isn't every letter only 1 char long? Sorry, I'm a beginner.

Comment: Sure, every character is one char long. Your string has `'_'` at index 0, `'_'` at index 1, `' '` at index 2 for your first letter of the word to guess. Then, `'_'` at index 3, `'_'` at index 4, `' '` at index 5 for the second letter of the word to guess and so on.